# Track SQL Database Tables in Visual Studio Solution in TFS

Tags: sql, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, tfs

The ASP.NET multilayered MVC project is currently on TFS now, but the database tables, scripts etc. are not in TFS.

So, database table changes etc are not being tracked/version controlled and we would want it to be, as it becomes difficult to verify which changes are in Staging and which are in Production.

The project has, Entity Framework Database first approach implemented currently.

So, what would be the best approach to start tracking the database too? The project is fairly small and will remain so too, so would something like Continuous Integration be a good approach?

If yes, are there any good articles showing approaches to move existing database tables to version-control?

Comment: Tip: any time you ask, "give me best approach", the question is too broad and opinion based. An these 2 conditions are not answerable in SO

Comment: OK Thanks, so how can I zero in on some best practices?

Comment: Google for patterns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you create a Database Project in your solution. By this, you have source and version control.

[How to: Create a New Database Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272677(v=vs.103).aspx)

[Creating a Visual Studio Database Project for an existing SQL Server Database](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2971/creating-a-visual-studio-database-project-for-an-existing-sql-server-database/)